# Java slf4j Best way to inject fixed parameters in every logged event

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I'm using slf4j + log4j in java to add logging to my web application. In each logged event I want to print the feature the user is executing and an identifier of the user action.

When my webapp catches the user's request, I generate the identifier and I have access to the feature "name". What is the best way to put these two parameters in every event logged without passing it out to every method log.(info|warn|debug|error)?

I know I can use MDC context to make the parameters visible for the whole thread and print them in the formatter of the logging statement.

```
log4j.appender.AppLog.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ddMMyyyyHHmmss}|%X{feature}|%-5p|%t|%l|%X{actionId}|%m%n
```

But I wanted a more controlled solution. Note that in the example above the feature and actionId aren't printed throught the logging message, but this isn't a requirement.

Comment: I suppose you can always write your own formatters.

Comment: I could write a custom formatter, but I haven't found a solution to make the feature name and actionID available in it. These are fixed parameters by user action/request of the same feature. Not global constants

Comment: Currently I only have these two parameters available in the request session.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
public MyClass {
     Logger log = new InterceptedLogger("com.foo.MyClass");

     // ...

     public void handleUserAction() {
        log.info("Action detected !");
        // ...
     }
}

public InterceptedLogger extends Logger {
     private static MyFramework myFrameWork = MyFramework.getInstance(); // or use an IoC to inject the instance for you...

     public InterceptedLogger(String name) {
         super(name);
     }

     public void info(Object message) {
        if (isInfoEnable()) {
           super.info( //
               String.format( //
                   "%s#%s - %s", // this format may be configured externally
                   myFrameWork.getCurrentUser(), //
                   myFrameWork.getCurrentAction(), //
                   message //
               ));
        }
     }

     // Override other methods as needed
}
```